# Random log events missing at logstash end

Tags: ruby, multithreading, logstash, elk

We are using filebeat as an input plugin and logstash as output. We are facing an issue where random logs are missing at logstash end. After troubleshooting this issue, we found a pattern that the logstash is failing to write few events with below error , which are eventually not listed in our logstash logs disk

```
Exception in thread "[main]>worker1" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:189)
        at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.bufferedWrite(ChannelStream.java:1100)
        at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.fwrite(ChannelStream.java:1277)
        at org.jruby.RubyIO.fwrite(RubyIO.java:1560)
        at org.jruby.RubyIO.write(RubyIO.java:1431)
        at org.jruby.RubyIO$INVOKER$i$1$0$write.call(RubyIO$INVOKER$i$1$0$write.gen)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callVarargs(CachingCallSite.java:103)
        at rubyjit.IOWriter$$write_0ea15f6ec0c1f5e822c7e5a2cc10c48da983df211442407170.__file__(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-file-4.0.1/lib/logstash
/outputs/file.rb:296)
        at rubyjit.IOWriter$$write_0ea15f6ec0c1f5e822c7e5a2cc10c48da983df211442407170.__file__(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-file-4.0.1/lib/logstash
/outputs/file.rb)
        at org.jruby.ast.executable.AbstractScript.__file__(AbstractScript.java:42)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:181)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
        at rubyjit.LogStash::Outputs::File$$multi_receive_encoded_0d69d585e7af8694d753496e5b730f68422a2ca21442407170.block_4$RUBY$__file__(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-file-4.0.1/lib/logstash/outputs/file.rb:133)
        at rubyjit$LogStash::Outputs::File$$multi_receive_encoded_0d69d585e7af8694d753496e5b730f68422a2ca21442407170$block_4$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$LogStash::Outputs::File$$multi_receive_encoded_0d69d585e7af8694d753496e5b730f68422a2ca21442407170$block_4$RUBY$__file__)
        at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock19.yield(CompiledBlock19.java:135)
        at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:142)
        at org.jruby.RubyArray.eachCommon(RubyArray.java:1606)
        at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(RubyArray.java:1613)
        at org.jruby.RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.call(RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.gen)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
        at rubyjit.LogStash::Outputs::File$$multi_receive_encoded_0d69d585e7af8694d753496e5b730f68422a2ca21442407170.block_3$RUBY$__file__(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-file-4.0.1/lib/logstash/outputs/file.rb:133)
        at rubyjit$LogStash::Outputs::File$$multi_receive_encoded_0d69d585e7af8694d753496e5b730f68422a2ca21442407170$block_3$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$LogStash::Outputs::File$$multi_receive_encoded_0d69d585e7af8694d753496e5b730f68422a2ca21442407170$block_3$RUBY$__file__)
        at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock19.yield(CompiledBlock19.java:135)
        at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:142)
        at org.jruby.RubyHash$13.visit(RubyHash.java:1355)
        at org.jruby.RubyHash.visitLimited(RubyHash.java:648)
        at org.jruby.RubyHash.visitAll(RubyHash.java:634)
        at org.jruby.RubyHash.iteratorVisitAll(RubyHash.java:1306)
        at org.jruby.RubyHash.each_pairCommon(RubyHash.java:1351)
        at org.jruby.RubyHash.each19(RubyHash.java:1342)
        at org.jruby.RubyHash$INVOKER$i$0$0$each19.call(RubyHash$INVOKER$i$0$0$each19.gen)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
        at rubyjit.LogStash::Outputs::File$$multi_receive_encoded_0d69d585e7af8694d753496e5b730f68422a2ca21442407170.block_2$RUBY$__file__(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/
gems/logstash-output-file-4.0.1/lib/logstash/outputs/file.rb:131)
        at rubyjit$LogStash::Outputs::File$$multi_receive_encoded_0d69d585e7af8694d753496e5b730f68422a2ca21442407170$block_2$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$LogStash::Outputs::File$$multi_
receive_encoded_0d69d585e7af8694d753496e5b730f68422a2ca21442407170$block_2$RUBY$__file__)

RROR -- : No space left on device (IOError)
org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1431:in `write'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-file-4.0.1/lib/logstash/outputs/file.rb:296:in `write'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-file-4.0.1/lib/logstash/outputs/file.rb:133:in `multi_receive_encoded'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-file-4.0.1/lib/logstash/outputs/file.rb:133:in `multi_receive_encoded'
org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-file-4.0.1/lib/logstash/outputs/file.rb:131:in `multi_receive_encoded'
org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149:in `synchronize'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-file-4.0.1/lib/logstash/outputs/file.rb:130:in `multi_receive_encoded'
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:90:in `multi_receive'
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator_strategies/shared.rb:12:in `multi_receive'
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:42:in `multi_receive'
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:297:in `output_batch'
org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'
log writing failed. No space left on device
[2021-07-23 07:04:05.747] ERROR -- : No space left on device (IOError)
org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1431:in `write'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-file-4.0.1/lib/logstash/outputs/file.rb:296:in `write'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-file-4.0.1/lib/logstash/outputs/file.rb:133:in `multi_receive_encoded'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-file-4.0.1/lib/logstash/outputs/file.rb:133:in `multi_receive_encoded'
org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-file-4.0.1/lib/logstash/outputs/file.rb:131:in `multi_receive_encoded'
org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149:in `synchronize'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-file-4.0.1/lib/logstash/outputs/file.rb:130:in `multi_receive_encoded'
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:90:in `multi_receive'
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator_strategies/shared.rb:12:in `multi_receive'
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:42:in `multi_receive'
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:297:in `output_batch'
org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'
```

on checking the method at file.rb on 133 line it is

```
      encoded_by_path.each do |path,chunks|
        fd = open(path)
        chunks.each {|chunk| fd.write(chunk) }
        fd.flush
```

Any inputs on what could be the issue can help us.

Comment: Can you share the full error? You cut the beginning of the stack trace, share from the start of with.

Comment: @leandrojmp Thanks for your reply. I have added the error stack trace